# api-maintenance@heroku.com: Detach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-contoured-49024)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku

I am new to Heroku and have deployed an application recently. It worked for a week before breaking. The issue lies on something related to Heroku. I see the following activity in Heroku.

```
api-maintenance@heroku.com: Detach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-contoured-49024)
```

Now when I access the application online I see:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
> If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

When I check the logs I see:

> F, [2022-12-19T11:51:30.936244 #4] FATAL -- :
> [bd4b4e41-9fc7-4d3d-b47b-f935f763a398]
> 2022-12-19T11:51:30.936316+00:00 app[web.1]:
> [bd4b4e41-9fc7-4d3d-b47b-f935f763a398]
> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (connection to server on socket
> "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory

It seems Heroku ran some sort of routine that screwed up the database. Can someone please advise on what I should do to get the app up and running again?

Thanks.

Comment: "It seems Heroku ran some sort of routine that screwed up the database"—did it stop working on or around November 28? Was it a free database? Heroku has stopped offering free services, as [announced on their blog over the summer](https://blog.heroku.com/next-chapter). Users with affected services also received a number of emails about this.

Comment: Yes it did. However I had moved to what they call the "Eco Dyno" which charges you a small amount. I am sure it is related to the changes in Heroku, however there is no info on how to solve the issue.

Comment: That's for your _dyno_, but free _databases_ were also eliminated. The cheapest Heroku Postgres offering is now called "mini", and it costs $5 a month. Did you make that change as well as moving to an eco dyno?

Comment: No, I was not aware of that. Thanks to your comment I managed to sort out the issue and subscribed to the "mini" postgres plan. I thought that the Eco Dyno covered that as well. Thank you so much for the help! :)